# Problem when I run my server on localhost (ruby on rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When I type rails server in my CMD the server works and I can go to localhost:3000.
But after i get this messege in the CMD and the same message in the browser on  localhost:3000 in the errors section.

```
Started GET "/rails/info/properties" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-02 21:14:55 +0200

Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)):

Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatc
h/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatc
h/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (30.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatc
h/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (97.0ms)
```

What is the issue?

here this is the database.yml file:

> # MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are
>   recommended.
>       #
>       # Install the MySQL driver:
>       #   gem install mysql2
>       #
>       # And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
>       #   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
>       development:
>         adapter: mysql2
>         encoding: utf8
>         reconnect: false
>         database: simple_cms_development
>         pool: 5
>         username: root
>         password:
>         host: localhost
>
> ```
> # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
> # re-generated from your development database when you run
> ```
>
> "rake".
>       # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
>       test:
>         adapter: mysql2
>         encoding: utf8
>         reconnect: false
>         database: simple_cms_test
>         pool: 5
>         username: root
>         password:
>         host: localhost
>
> ```
> production:
>   adapter: mysql2
>   encoding: utf8
>   reconnect: false
>   database: simple_cms_production
>   pool: 5
>   username: root
>   password:passwordex
>   host: localhost
> ```

Comment: Your MySQL DB server isn't allowing access by root. What users are configured for MySQL?

Comment: i think everyone.. the defuelt, how can i change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using root for your mysql user, but not supplying the root password in config/database.yml.

Incidentally, while its usually ok in development, using the root mysql user in production or for staging is a Very Bad Idea™.

here's a typical mysql config section:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: app_production
  username: root
  password: password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8
```

Comment: 10x!!! so what i shoud write here="password:" in the file config/database.yml ? i wrote just the password for exmpale: "pass1234" like this: password: pass1234 , and it telling me the syntix is worng whats worng? 10x agin man!

Comment: ArgumentError

syntax error on line 38, col 1: ` password123 host: localhost'

Comment: You'll have to paste your database.yml file.  Please edit your question to include that so that formatting is preserved.

Comment: you need a space after "password:" => "password: password"

Comment: Also, make sure you're running the environment you expect to be running.  if you just run "script/server" or "rails server" you're going to be in the development environment, not production, so make sure you set the database password there.

Comment: ohh in the development: i need to write the password i wrote in the MySql configrtion? and what password shoud i write in the production?

Comment: the formatting is still screwy, so its difficult to tell in your database.yml.  Remove everything except one environment, and run in that environment (e.g. RAILS_ENV=production ./script/server)  From the error you've got it looks as though you've got password and host on the same line, which is wrong.  Also, make sure you're using spaces instead of tab chars in the file.

Comment: you should use whatever the password is for the mysql user you're using.  On your development machine, they're probably the same.

Answer (score 3):

I know you already found the solution to your problem, but I'm going to post this as an answer anyways, for those who might stumble across this same issue.

Having the same exact `Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` problem, it turns out my `database.yml` file was malformatted. The reason? YAML doesn't allow certain characters: I happened to be using a '!' in my password, and for whatever reason, the YAML parser reading this `database.yml` file ignored my password line like it wasn't there, hence the `(using password: NO)`, even though I explicitly declared it.

Solution? Changed my password not to include any YAML special characters. I suppose there might be a way to escape it, though. Annoying nonetheless.

Comment: You can also wrap it in quotes.